# javascript - how to open a new popup with query parameters

Tags: javascript

I would like to use Javascript to popup a new window with query paramters. For example (www.google.com/ref=tag?value=5). Even when I passed in "www.google.com/ref=tag?value=5" as the URL to window.open, the query parameters (ref=tag?value=5) are ignore. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/ref=tag?value=5','_blank')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me on Firefox - typing the following in the URL area popped up the correct URL in a new window:

```
javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/ref=tag?value=5')
```

Can you provide your exact JavaScript code that doesn't work?